# List items and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code here: [codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wiBmn)

Basically, the way the list items SHOULD react is that the new items that are added (The ones WITH the checkbox showing) should be like the already placed list item (the one that background changes when clicked). The count should also go up. I don't know why my current method doesn't work, as it's written the same way the other code is...

CODE:

HTML:

```
<div class='navbar navbar-fixed-bottom'>
            <div class='col-lg-3 col-offset-2 pull-left'>
                <form class="navbar-form pull-left">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="filtr" id="filtr" placeholder="Search..">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class='container'>
                <a class='navbar-brand' href='#'></a>
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav pull-right'>
                    <li><a href='#' class='count'><strong>0</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Next Step <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right v-align-middle"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='contains'>
            <ul class='list-unstyled' id="productlist">
                <label for="addbox"><li class="products" id="addbox">+ NON-STOCKED ITEM</li></label>
                <label for="nonitem"><li class='products NON-STOCKED0'>NON-STOCKED ITEM<input class="hide" type="checkbox" id="nonitem" value="NON-STOCKED ITEM"><span class='selectedbox pull-right large-icon'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span></li></label>
                    <span id='newbox'></span>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){ 
                var count = 0;
                var newdiv = $("#newbox");
                var nonitem = $("#nonitem")
                var a = $(nonitem).size() + 1;
                var b = $(nonitem).size() + 1;

                a = a -1;
                b = b -1;

                $("#addbox").click(function(){
                    $("<label for='nonitem"+a+"' id='chk'><li class='products NON-STOCKED'>NON-STOCKED ITEM<input class='' type='checkbox' id='nonitem"+b+"' value='NON-STOCKED ITEM'></li></label>").appendTo(newdiv);
                    a++;
                    b++;
                    return false;
                });

                $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
                    $(this).parent().toggleClass("backchange");
                    $(this).next(".selectedbox").fadeToggle();
                    var check = this.checked? 1 : -1;
                    count = count + check;
                    $(".count").text(count);
                    if(count >= 1){
                        $(".clearall").fadeIn();
                        $(".count").addClass("countplus");
                    }else{
                        $(".clearall").fadeOut();
                        $(".count").removeClass("countplus");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Post your relevant code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ilpqk

Problem was that the jquery `.click()` is only applied when the document was loaded, so the inserted elements didn't get the new class applied. use `.on()` instead.

So in short, I changed `$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){` to `$(document).on("click","input[type='checkbox']",function(){`

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll mark this as the answer after a few minutes when it lets me. EDIT - Done.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `hide` class in to your input checkbox. This will hide the check box.

Also your event binding is for the already present element and won't apply to dynamically added listing.

change

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
 // your code
});
```

to

```
$('.list-unstyled').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"], function(){
 // your code
});
```

this will delegate the event to parent element to watch for the click on child selector.

Comment: I un-hid the checkbox so that you guys knew which list item I meant wasn't working. Thank you though! Upvoted for helping!